# Detect gesture over all application

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Im intenting to detect all Double-Finger Swipe-Down gesture over my application.

I've extended the Window class, and added this:

```
public extension UIWindow {

    func initGestureTouch() {
        let swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleGesture))
        swipeDown.direction = .down
        swipeDown.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2
        self.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)
    }
}
```

It's working almost everywhere but on ScrollViews (TableViews, etc). In this views only the scrollview get the gesture.

Is there a way to do this? It's a special gesture, used to open an Helper Assistent.

Ps: Until now, the only way I've found is adding a double gesture detection on every scrollview, but it's not enough to me.

Comment: Can you write full code, How you extending the Window class ?

Comment: I've edited my question. So in appDelegate (didFinishLauching...) I added this: self.window?.initGestureTouch()

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
swipeDown.cancelsTouchesInView = True
swipeDown.delaysTouchesBegan = True
```

The first will mean touches will not be sent to views below if recognised.
The second will delay when the touches are sent.